# Black Hole limit from Morris-Thorne wormhole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, wormholes

I have to show that Morris-Thorne wormhole given by the metric
$$ds^2=-e^{2 \Phi}dt^2+\frac{1}{1-\frac{b}{r}}dr+r^2(d \theta^2+\sin^2 \theta
\ d \varphi^2)$$
has a black hole limit (or maybe flat or AdS limit). I set $b=b_0=\text{const}$ (à la Schwarzschild) and $\rho \rightarrow \epsilon \rho$ , $\tau \rightarrow \epsilon \rho$ , and  $p \rightarrow \epsilon p$ in stress-energy tensor, since in BH limit all of the components $T^{\mu \nu}$ must vanish. I must somehow rescale my metric in terms of $\epsilon$ and see how my solution goes to the black hole solution. How can I do that?

Comment: Are $\Phi$ and $b$ functions of $r$ only?  What does the stress energy tensor of this metric look like, so that those limits you take make sense?  Also, note that Schwarzschild is a vacuum solution.  If you are taking a limit where something is becoming Schwarzschild, then, the matter should be becoming zero.  Also, consider the Birchoff theorem and the form of that metric.